# Postback a clicked row in the list of items in MVC razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC4 and razor view. I am binding a list of items in the page. I want to post back a single item after clicking the specific row. e.g.

```
ID    FName   LName
1     xxxx    xxxx
2     xxxx    xxxx
```

When the user clicks "1" (the first row) it should post back the entire row to the server. Where "1" is a link or a button.

I have tried with

```
<a href='@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName", Object)'>
  1
</a>
```

but it is passing the values in the url which i don't want. Is it good to surround each `<a>` with `<form>` element? Any otherway?

Please Note: It should not be the ajax way and it should not post back as query string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking on a link will do a GET action. Since you do not want to send values as querystring values, this is not an option.

You should create a `form` tag inside each row with a submit button. Keep the values you want to post to the server in hidden fields.

Assuming your view is strongly typed to a list of ProductViewModel class ojects which has `Id` and `Name` properties.

```
public class ProductViewModel 
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public string Name {set;get;}
}
```

And your view

```
@model List<ProductViewModel>
<h2>Products</h2>
<table>
@foreach(var item in Model.Products)
{
<tr>
    <td>@item.Id</td>
    <td>@item.Name</td>       
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
        {
            <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" name="Id" />
            <input type="hidden" value="@item.Name" name="Name" />                    
            <input type="submit" />
        }
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

And you should have an HttpPost action method to accept this form posting. The parameter name should match with your hidden input field names.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int Id, string Name)
{         
    // to do : return something.
}
```

Or you may use your `ProductViewModel` class as the parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel model)
{         
    // to do : return something.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju! Just wondering is it possible to post the clicked row data with a single <form></form> element. Anyway.. your code makes sense. Thanks!